# How to speed up Drawing of DrawGrid Cells (Delphi)

Tags: performance, delphi

I have a DrawGrid with 600 x 600 Cells.
Each Cell gets painted with a color dependig on its Value.
Displaying the Grid needs ~1 second.

Question is: how can this be improved, so drawing needs less time?

The OnDrawCell Event looks like:
(MyVal is the Col/Row value and is taken from an 2 dimensional Array)

```
...
MyVal := MyArray[ACol, ARow];
case MyVal of 
  0: Drawgrid1.Canvas.brush.Color := clRed;
  1: Drawgrid1.Canvas.brush.Color := clBlue;
  ...
end;
Drawgrid1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
Drawgrid1.Canvas.fillrect(Rect);
```

Thank you.

Klaus

Comment: Are you showing all the cells at once?

Comment: How much does it take to display the grid when you don't draw anything yourself?

Comment: How big is each row/col? Do you have all 600x600 in view at the same time? Or does it scroll over/down? Because grids are only supposed to draw the individual cells as they're visible to the user. Cells which are hidden due to scrolling aren't supposed to draw at all, until the user scrolls them into view.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
All 600x 600 cells are displayed,.
Each cell has 1x1 Pixel, so no need to scroll

The Application supports zoom, so it may also have 2x2 pixels.

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino
if no drawing is done, it takes ~ 100ms.

Comment: Kalus i know that is not the answer that you are looking, but i believe that a grid is not the best component to do it. If you need these kind of image functions (zoom etc), you need to write direct in the canvas, on the grid you you have a lot of overhead, by the size of the matrix this time is not that bad taking in consideration the amount operations that the grid does underneath.

Comment: I'd suggest a test with double buffering.

Comment: 360000 1x1 px cells, wut?

Comment: @Klaus.Meier As Rodrigo already said don't use draw grid for this. It was never intended for any such jobs so it won't offer you good enough performance. Since you are talking about 1x1 pixel grid and possibility to zoom I think the best bet would be to draw on TBitmap and then scale-draw that bitmap onto any canvas to reach desired zoom level.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.